# Lzo files not getting split in hive jobs

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, lzo

We have 3 .lzo files and the corresponding .index files in s3.
We are creating a external table on the directory of these files.
Size of the each lzo file is 100MB+ and uncomporessed size of each file is 800+MB
Block size is 128MB.
When we run hive queries , unfortunately only 3 mappers are being spawned, suggesting that splitting is not happening, what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Splittable applies only when size of the compressed file is greater than split size. Hive default split size is 256 MB.

Modify split size in the hive session and run the query.

```
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=64000000
```

Comment: this is not working, tried setting the mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize to 32 MB and it doesnt work. As per the split calculation formula, we need to set the maxsize parameter and not minsize as suggested,also tried setting min and max to 32 MB, still doesnt work...any other suggestions?

Comment: It could be due to s3.

Comment: we tested in a non aws cluster, still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Everything has been set 30MB.

```
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=31457280;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=31457280;
set dfs.blocksize=31457280;
```

Still we see that number of mappers remains same. This is done on normal cluster not on S3.
We are seeing only 10 mappers for 3 LZO files of size (229.16 MB, 705.79 MB, 157.61 MB)